# How can I save a Swift dictionary structure?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, collections, save

I have a Swift dictionary structure (`[String : CustomObject]`) that I need to save once and then reload later whenever the application launches. How do I go about saving and reloading a dictionary using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the Dictionary to **NSData** [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376469/nsdictionary-to-nsdata-and-nsdata-to-nsdictionary-in-swift) and then save it to **NSUserDefaults** as it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224808/converting-swift-array-to-nsdata-for-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults-persist)

Comment: I've tried this, but my dictionary is of type [String : Word] not [String: AnyObject] so it does not work. Word is a custom class I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom objects then you need to make them conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. This means implementing the methods `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder`. It comes down to deconstructing the state values of your object to data types that are either "property list" types, or types that also conform to `NSCoding`. Your implementation of encodeWithCoder can, encode it's properties that are objects that conform to NSCoding by calling `encodeObject:forKey:`